# -Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#

Continuous data is coming from the serial port.I'm transferring data from the serial port to the c # ms chart. but I am encountering this error. I looked at a few solutions but I couldn't understand.

## codes

```
    ConcurrentQueue<string> kuyruk = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    string result;

    private void addPoint()
    {
        string pnt;
        while (true)
        {
            if (!kuyruk.IsEmpty)
            {
                if (kuyruk.TryDequeue(out pnt))
                    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(pnt);
            }
        }
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
            var indata = serialPort1.ReadChar();
            if (indata != 13 && indata != 10)
                result += Convert.ToChar(indata);
            else
            {
                if (result != null)
                    kuyruk.Enqueue(result.ToString());
                result = null;
            }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.Open();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(addPoint));
        thread.Start();
    }
```

## error

[image]

## details

[image]

Comment: Which line of code does the error appear on?

Comment: Program.cs's Application.Run (new Form1 ()); in line

Comment: Could you please post exception details? What does it say when you click "Ayrıntıları Görüntüle" ?

Comment: I added to the question

Comment: Please, please copy the stack trace and paste it as text. You are appending elements to `chart1.Series[0].Points` from a background thread. It is interesting that you are not getting an `Illegal Cross Thread Call` (InvalidOperationException) exception, but I think the chart component (what chart is it by the way?) iterates over this point collection at the same time and hence the exception.

Comment: To prevent this, you can try to add a custom event to your form, attach to this event in your form during initialization, and raise this event from your background thread. That's the way to execute code on the UI thread even if it is triggered by a background worker.

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: Hi. Can you please mark as answer if it helped? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is how to do it (safely).

### Root cause:

You are manipulating a collection from a background thread which is at the same time being iterated through by a form component on the main (UI) thread.

### Solution:

To add to the collection safely, you should do it on the main thread. Windows Forms framework provides ways to achieve this. One of them is as follows.

The approach implemented here has been tested and proved positive. (The points added by the background thread were successfully rendered by the chart component)

Add a delegate accepting a string parameter to your form class:

```
public delegate void OnSerialDataReceived(string pnt);
```

Add a method accepting a string parameter to your form class. This method will be used as the concrete implementation of the delegate.

```
    private void AddPointToChart(string pnt)
    {
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(pnt);
    }
```

When you dequeue new data from your concurrent queue, do the following instead of adding the point directly:

```
    private void addPoint()
    {
        string pnt;
        while (true)
        {
            if (!kuyruk.IsEmpty)
            {
                if (kuyruk.TryDequeue(out pnt))
                {
                    // This will guarantee safe invocation of the target method
                    // on the UI thread
                    var safeInvoker = new OnSerialDataReceived(AddPointToChart);
                    chart1.Invoke(safeInvoker, pnt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

That's all.

Good luck.

Comment: Can you mark as answer if it did? Thanks and you’re welcome

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you have an `infinte loop` here:

```
   while (true)
    {
        if (!kuyruk.IsEmpty)
        {
            if (kuyruk.TryDequeue(out pnt))
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(pnt);
        }
    }
```

That's why you are getting an InvalidOperationException. Put a condition for breaking out of the `while-loop`.

If the problem continues, leave a comment.

Comment: I think the infinite loop is intentional in this case. The OP seems to be reading data from a serial port. I think the real problem is related to adding the point to the chart. Something must be looping over the chart property collection and the code keeps changing the collection during enumeration.

Comment: @Ndubuisi the problem still continues. My condition serialPort1.IsOpen

Comment: @Doug Dawson  What do you suggest I do.

Comment: @İdrisBolge Try retrieving all the data first before you add it to the series point.

Comment: Will that fit your use case?

Comment: my goal is to write if there is data in the queue. I want this thread to work as data arrives.

Comment: @İdrisBolge, can you show us the code where you're looping over the 'chart1.Series[0].Points' collection? Add it to your post and we can take a look.

Comment: I'm not making a loop for the chart. There is only one code related to the graphic. This is the addition command. ie "chart1.Series [0] .Points.AddY (pnt);"

I'm just adding dots to the graphic in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

@Oguz Ozgul

```
 System.InvalidOperationException
      HResult=0x80131509
      İleti=Koleksiyon değiştirildi; sabit listesi işlemi yürütülemeyebilir.
      Kaynak=mscorlib
      StackTrace:
       konum System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
       konum System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
       konum System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
       konum System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartTypes.FastLineChart.Paint(ChartGraphics graph, CommonElements common, ChartArea area, Series seriesToDraw)
       konum System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.Paint(ChartGraphics graph)
       konum System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPicture.Paint(Graphics graph, Boolean paintTopLevelElementOnly)
       konum System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
       konum System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
       konum System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
       konum System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       konum System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       konum System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       konum System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

      Bu özel durum özgün olarak bu çağrı yığınında oluşturuldu: 
        [Dış Kod]
```

Comment: As I suspected, the chart is Painting at the moment you are adding the point. I will post an answer if you have 5 minutes.